# ValueError: Type must be a sub-type of ndarray type

Tags: python

when i try to train my model,

`"ValueError: Type must be a sub-type of ndarray type"`

arises at `line x_norm=(np.power(x,2)).sum(1).view(-1,1)` .

Code :

```
def pairwise_distances(x, y=None):
  
  x_norm = (np.power(x,2)).sum(1).view(-1, 1)

   if y is not None:
   y_t = torch.transpose(y, 0, 1)
   y_norm = (y**2).sum(1).view(1, -1)
  else:
   y_t = torch.transpose(x, 0, 1)
   y_norm = x_norm.view(1, -1)

  dist = x_norm + y_norm - 2.0 * torch.mm(x, y_t)
  # Ensure diagonal is zero if x=y
  # if y is None:
  #     dist = dist - torch.diag(dist.diag)
  return torch.clamp(dist, 0.0, np.inf)
```

Comment: Do you know the type of x?

Comment: type of x is a list

Comment: I would suggest that you split the creation of the x_norm into 3 steps and call them separately. This would help you find out which function call is returning the error. And I have another question: What should the line returning the error do?

Comment: File "/content/drive/My Drive/tirg/tirg/torch_functions.py", line 41, in pairwise_distances
    x_norm = (np.power(x, 2)).sum(1).view(1,-1)
ValueError: Type must be a sub-type of ndarray type
Training for epoch 0:   0% 0/594 [00:29<?, ?it/s]

Comment: self.distances = pairwise_distances(features).cpu().numpy()
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/tirg/tirg/torch_functions.py", line 45, in pairwise_distances
    v=u.view(1,-1)
ValueError: Type must be a sub-type of ndarray type

Comment: self.distances = row_pairwise_distances(features).cpu().numpy()
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/tirg/tirg/torch_functions.py", line 35, in row_pairwise_distances
    dtype = x.data.type()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data

Comment: How to remove AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: def row_pairwise_distances(x, y=None, dist_mat=None):
 
    if y is None:
      y = x
    if dist_mat is None:
      dtype = x.data.type()
      dist_mat = Variable(torch.Tensor(x.size()[0], y.size()[0]).type(dtype))

    for i, row in enumerate(x.split(1)):
      r_v = row.expand_as(y)
      sq_dist = torch.sum((r_v - y) ** 2, 1)
      dist_mat[i] = sq_dist.view(1, -1)
      return dist_mat

Comment: Sir, your Text image residual gate project implemented on which python and torch version ,i unable to implement in python 3.6.8 and  Torch1.0.0. I  want to use this module in my research..but unable to fix the pairwaise_distances function problem..............Help me out so i proceed in positive direction...

Answer (score 9):

Numpy array `view` is different from torch tensor `view`.
In [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view):

```
ndarray.view([dtype][, type])
    New view of array with the same data.
```

In [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view):

```
view(*shape) → Tensor
    Returns a new tensor with the same data as the self tensor but of a different shape.
```

Numpy's `view` changes the data type of the array, not the shape.
If you want to change the shape of the array in numpy, use [`ndarray.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) instead.

Comment: how does that explain the error

Comment: @stunlocked It is based on my assumption that op did not notice he converted the data to numpy, hence asking why torch.tensor.view is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to @Kallzvx's answer that ndarray.view CAN change the shape of the array. For instance

```
array_uint16 = np.ones((10, 10, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
array_uint16.view(np.uint32).shape
> (10, 10, 1)
```

According to the documentation,

> For a.view(some_dtype), if some_dtype has a different number of bytes per entry than the previous dtype (for example, converting a regular array to a structured array), then the last axis of a must be contiguous. This axis will be resized in the result.